# Two Texts in a Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, countif

Probably an incredibly easy change but I seem to have a brain fart in this. I have a column and I want my formula to search for both "Open" and "In-Transit".

```
=COUNTIFS('Warner Robins'!A:A,"Open",'Warner Robins'!G:G, "PAB")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps:

```
=COUNTIFS('Warner Robins'!A:A,"Open",'Warner Robins'!G:G, "PAB")+COUNTIFS('Warner Robins'!A:A,"In-Transit",'Warner Robins'!G:G, "PAB")
```

Building an *OR* into a formula can be tough...........easier to just add up the cases.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Idk what I was doing in my formula but I did try adding another COUNTIFS function but it wasn't coming out correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can go with this one:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS('Warner Robins'!A:A,{"Open","In-Transit"},'Warner Robins'!G:G, "PAB"))
```

Generally makes it easier for multiple `OR` clauses.